# How to set read only UISlider?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch

My UISlider is used to keep progress of a playing song.

Although the user can't change the progress it still allows it to change the state of the control.

How do I prevent the user to change the UISlider by tapping on it?

Comment: Not a good idea - a slider is there to let the user change a value. Users know that and expect that they can use it to change the playing position using that sliders.

Comment: Is it very hard to allow users to, say, go back a few seconds?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First let me say, have you looked into use [UIProgressView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIProgressView_Class/Reference/Reference.html)?

It should give you exactly what you want without needed to disable user input.

---

To answer your question directly, have you tried `slider.userInteractionEnabled = NO`?